# Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I currently try to get a json but i always get a error

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { (req, res, json) -> Void in
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(json.value!)
            print(swiftyJsonVar)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message reveals that the return type of the closure is a single object rather than three.

Two suggestions to get the proper syntax quickly:

- use code completion.
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on the symbol or look at Quick Help (<kbd>⌥⌘2</kbd>) to read the documentation.

In your case the `request` method returns one `response` object

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            print(swiftyJsonVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Alamofire.request("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in            
        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            print(resJson)
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is for swift 3 & Alamofire 4